# ¿Cómo lograr que los botones tengan el mismo ancho con CSS?

Tags: bootstrap, css3

Me gustaría que los 3 botones tengan el mismo ancho y un poco de separación a los lados.

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

El CSS no es lo mío :(

Código:

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="{{ route('publicaciones.show', $id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Ver</a>
    <a href="{{ route('publicaciones.show', $id)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Editar</a>

    <form method="POST" action="{{ url("publicaciones/{$id}") }}">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit">Eliminar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Adjunto resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Comment: Hola, podrias ver si inspeccionas elemento sobre los 2 botones si estos tienen un padding-bottom de mas?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con

```
<div class="row">
<a href="{{ route('publicaciones.show', $id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm col">Ver</a>
<a href="{{ route('publicaciones.show', $id)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm col">Editar</a>

<form method="POST" action="{{ url("publicaciones/{$id}") }}" class="col">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit">Eliminar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias Genaro pero los botones de ver y editar siguen utilizando todo el ancho

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row {
  width: 15em;
  height: 2em;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  gap: 0 .4em;
}

.row a {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  
  /*para centrar enlace de manera vertical*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row form {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.row form button {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: rgb(226, 53, 44);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

/*estilos extra de diseño*/
.row a:first-child {
  background: rgb(56, 193, 115);
}

.row a:nth-child(2) {
  background: rgb(59, 151, 224);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <a href="{{ route('publicaciones.show', $id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Ver</a>
    <a href="{{ route('publicaciones.show', $id)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Editar</a>

    <form method="POST" action="{{ url("publicaciones/{$id}") }}">
        
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit">Eliminar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```